# Routes to a controller not in controller directory

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I like to test a test implementation of my controller which is in `Bundle/Controller` directory. My test controller which extends this controller is in `Bundle/Tests/Resources/Controller`.

How can I access this controller on my `routing_test.yml` file?

I tried like this:

```
_test_api_delete:
    path: /api/test/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: Bundle:Tests/Resources/Controller/TestController:delete }
    methods: [DELETE]
```

But symfony does not find the controller. Is there any possbility to link a route to a controller which is not in the default `Bundle/Controller` directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the fully-qualified class name:

```
_test_api_delete:
    path: /api/test/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: Acme\SomeBundle\Tests\Resources\Controller\TestController::deleteAction }
    methods: [DELETE]
```